# How can i have hot redeploy in production mode in play framework 2 apps?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, production, hotdeploy, redeploy

I know that play framework 2 support hot code reloading in development mode, I want to know how can i have hot redeploy in production mode in play framework 2 apps?
Is there a transparent approach to do this? something like using load balancer or native approach is acceptable to me.

Comment: Dev mode isn't really hot reloading. The server is completely restarted after recompiling.

Answer (score 2):

Load balancing is a natural choice with play because of it's stateless nature. You can deploy on one instance at a time, and your application will remain available all the time as long as the other instances are UP.

Once the application deployed put it back to the load balancer and end users will not notice any outage

Answer (score 0):

It is to late to answer this, but using remote debugger you can hot swap java classes

```
$ jdb -attach 192.168.2.241:9999
> redefine com.ClassName /path/to/project/target/scala-2.12/classes/com/ClassName.class
```